# change signal disposition of already running process (SIGHUP)

Tags: linux

Let's say I started Linux process, in the background. It is not a daemon, just a utility.
If it gets SIGHUP, it would be killed.

I did not take the "nohup" precaution. It is taking already much longer time than I thought.
After 4 hours of running, ssh session might get disconnected.  But I don't want to lose the process.
I want to prevent it being killed by SIGHUP.

Is it possible to make the equivalent of

```
   signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
```

to this process without restarting it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `disown(1)`

> disown: disown [-h] [-ar] [jobspec
>   ...]
>       Remove jobs from current shell.
>
> ```
> Removes each JOBSPEC argument from the table of active jobs.  Without
> any JOBSPECs, the shell uses its notion of the current job.
>
> Options:
>   -a        remove all jobs if JOBSPEC is not supplied
>   -h        mark each JOBSPEC so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if
>             the shell receives a SIGHUP
>   -r        remove only running jobs
> ```

[Detaching a process from terminal, entirely](https://superuser.com/questions/178587/detaching-a-process-from-terminal-entirely/178592#178592)

> "disown" is a bash builtin that
>   removes a shell job from the shell's
>   job list. What this basically means is
>   that you can't use "fg", "bg" on it
>   anymore, but more importantly, when
>   you close your shell it won't hang or
>   send a SIGHUP to that child anymore.
>   Unlike "nohup", "disown" is used after
>   the process has been launched and
>   backgrounded.

Answer (score 2):

Diswon is the good solution for this time.
For the future, a nice workaround is to use "screen" tool : if ever your ssh session disconnects, you can reconnect and refetch your still running screen.

However, I don't know a way to pull a current process into a screen session, so it won't solve your current case.

Comment: [`reptyr`](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) is a beautifully disgusting hack that can switch the controlling terminal of an already-running process.